# Wpf - how to get textbox value based on combobox selection

Tags: wpf, linq, combobox, textbox

I have a  model `CATEGORY` in which I have two properties `NAME` n `DESCRIPTION`. Now my combo box uses `NAME` as item. On selecting a NAME in combo box I want my textbox's text property to have the `DESCRIPTION` of that category `NAME`.

I m using Linq for database queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the `TextBox` Text Value to the `ComboBox`'s `SelectedItem` using the `ComboBox` `ElementName`, and here how to :

```
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Loaded="MainWindow_OnLoaded">
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.Description, ElementName=CatComboBox}"/>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListCategories}" x:Name="CatComboBox" DisplayMemberPath="Name"></ComboBox>        
</StackPanel>
```

i am setting this window `DataContext` to its code Behind which looks like this :

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window,INotifyPropertyChanged 
{

    private ObservableCollection<Category> _listCategories;    
    public ObservableCollection<Category> ListCategories
    {
        get
        {
            return _listCategories;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_listCategories == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _listCategories = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MainWindow_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Get the data from the DB
        ListCategories=new ObservableCollection<Category>()
        {
            new Category()
            {
                Name = "Name1",
                Description = "Descrition1"
            },
            new Category()
            {
                Name = "Name2",
                Description = "Descrition2"
            }
        };
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

the model :

```
public class Category
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
}
```